# Why is the linewidth inconsistent for this animated LineCollection?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

This animation is supposed to particles in motion with the leading component having alpha=1 and lw=4, with a tail of reducing lw and alpha. The alpha works, the lw is **inconsistent** even for the same particle - sometimes the leading edge is fat and the tail thin, sometimes the obverse is true. Why?!

Note - I'm, actually modelling traffic around a network, but I thought this multiple particle random walk would be a good example. For my use case the tail will be fairly crucial for the clarity and visibility of the final graphic.

##### Fake data summary values

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib import cm
from functools import partial

np.random.seed(42) # to match my example
n_particles = 50 # number of particles to simulate
n_frames = 500 # number of frames to simulate
fade_frames = 5 # number of frames to fade out the animated plots for
# set up particle stating points & ids
particle_ids = [f"p{i}" for i in  range(1, n_particles+1)]
starting_x = np.random.uniform(40, 60, n_particles)
starting_y = np.random.uniform(40, 60, n_particles)
# randomly assign start & end lives of points
start_frames = np.random.randint(0, n_frames/2, n_particles)
end_frames = start_frames + np.random.randint(n_frames/4, n_frames/2, n_particles)
colours = np.random.choice(range(10), n_particles) # Range 10 to match colours in the "tab10" colourmap

particles = pd.DataFrame({"id": particle_ids, "starting_x": starting_x, "starting_y": starting_y, "start_frames": start_frames, "end_frames": end_frames, "colour":colours})#.sort_values("start_frames").reset_index(drop=True)
```

##### Inflate data to get positions of all particles in each frame

My true data looks like this:

```
particle_ids = []
x_loc = []
y_loc = []
frames = []
colours = []

for id in particles.id:
    start_frame = particles.loc[particles.id == id, "start_frames"].values[0]
    end_frame = particles.loc[particles.id == id, "end_frames"].values[0]
    colour = particles.loc[particles.id == id, "colour"].values[0]
    
    particle_ids.append(id)
    colours.append(colour)
    x_loc.append(particles.loc[particles.id == id, "starting_x"].values[0])
    y_loc.append(particles.loc[particles.id == id, "starting_y"].values[0])
    frames.append(start_frame)
    
    for frame in range(start_frame+1, end_frame+1):
        particle_ids.append(id)
        colours.append(colour)
        x_loc.append(x_loc[-1] + np.random.uniform(-2, 2))
        y_loc.append(y_loc[-1] + np.random.uniform(-2, 2))
        frames.append(frame)
        
movements = (pd.DataFrame({
    "id": particle_ids, 
    "x_loc": x_loc, 
    "y_loc": y_loc, 
    "frame": frames, 
    "colour":colours})
    .sort_values("frame")
    .reset_index(drop=True))

# replace colour code with rgb values. Set alpha during animation
cmap = dict(zip(range(10), cm.tab10.colors))
movements['colour'] = movements.colour.map(cmap)
```

##### Run the animation

```
# Set up plot
xmin = movements.x_loc.min()
xmax = movements.x_loc.max()
ymin = movements.y_loc.min()
ymax = movements.y_loc.max()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
ax.set_xlim(0,100)
ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
lines = LineCollection([], ) # empty container to update later
ax.add_collection(lines)

def animate(frame, lines):
    # Get data for the current frame
    start_frame = frame - fade_frames
    if frame >= movements.frame.max():
        end_frame = movements.frame.max()
    else:
        end_frame = frame
    if start_frame <= 0:
        start_frame = 0
        end_frame = 1
    all_segments = []
    all_colours = []
    all_linewidths = []
    frame_slice = movements[(start_frame<=movements.frame) & (movements.frame<=end_frame)]

    # plot LineCollection for each particle separately
    for id, grp in frame_slice.groupby('id'):
        coords = list(zip(grp.x_loc.tolist(), grp.y_loc.tolist()))
        all_segments.extend([(coords[i-1], coords[i]) for i in range(1, len(coords))])
        colours = grp.colour.tolist()[:-1]
        fade_values = [(frame-start_frame)/fade_frames for frame in grp.frame]
        rgba = [(r,g,b,a) for (r,g,b), a in zip(colours, fade_values)]
        all_colours.extend(rgba)
        all_linewidths.extend([4*val for val in fade_values])
        
    ax.draw_artist(lines)
    lines.set_segments(all_segments)
    lines.set_color(all_colours)
    lines.set_linewidth(all_linewidths)
    return lines,

# Run animation
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig, 
    partial(animate, lines=lines), 
    frames=n_frames, 
    interval=100, 
    repeat_delay=200, 
    blit=True)

ani.save('test.gif')
plt.show()
```

[image: particles on a random walk]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an off-by-1 indexing problem with creating `fade_values`.

```
    frame_slice = movements[(start_frame<=movements.frame) & (movements.frame<=end_frame)]
    #this generates 6 frames because you include both the start and end frames (which you need because N line segments requires N+1 vertexes.
    for id, grp in frame_slice.groupby('id'):
        coords = list(zip(grp.x_loc.tolist(), grp.y_loc.tolist()))
        all_segments.extend([(coords[i-1], coords[i]) for i in range(1, len(coords))])
        #iterating from 1-len here reduces the frame count (correctly?) to 5 because you need
        #  6 vertices to make 5 line segments
        colours = grp.colour.tolist()[1:] 
        #all points from groupby should have the same colour anyway
        fade_values = [(frame-start_frame)/fade_frames for frame in grp.frame.tolist()[1:]]
        #Here's the fix! you need to throw out the first frame as you have 1 more frame than line segments.
        rgba = [(r,g,b,a) for (r,g,b), a in zip(colours, fade_values)]
        all_colours.extend(rgba)
        all_linewidths.extend([4*val for val in fade_values])
```

Comment: nuts. I also have a problem of lining up the color and alpha and segment values then as the segment length = n_points-1 but the colors and alpha lengths = n_points. Any suggestions?

Comment: I didn't go hard checking all the +1 -1 offsets, but you got the general idea.